# Create a function in Python that has as input a forloop

Tags: python, function, for-loop

I’m trying to define a function that takes as input 8 different values using a forloop and returns the average the minimum and the maximum of the inputs that have been inserted.
What am I doing wrong?

I tried in this way:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n9sgD.png)

```
def x(u):
      for i in range(8):
        c=float(input())
      y=0
      values=[]
      values.append(c)
      avg=(y+c)/8
      return avg, ("The maximum is {:.0f}".format(max(values))),("The minimum 
      is {:.0f}".format(min(values)))
      print(x(1))
```

Edit:
thanks you for your suggestions,I tried with your code but it gives me this error: int' object is not callable

Here is the new code:

```
 def function():
  values = []
  for i in range(8):  
      x=(float(input()))
      values.append(x)
  mean = float(sum(values)/len(values))
  return mean, max(values), min(values)
    
 print(function())
TypeError      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-245-dbc2112cdcc7> in <module>
      8   return mean, max(values), min(values)
      9 
---> 10 print(function())

<ipython-input-245-dbc2112cdcc7> in function()
      5       x=(float(input()))
      6       values.append(x)
----> 7   mean = float(sum(values)/len(values))
      8   return mean, max(values), min(values)
      9 

TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Comment: you must post your code as text, not an image! collect your inputs into some collection (perhaps a list `my_list = []` .. `my_list.append(value)`)

Answer (score 0):

At every iteration of the for loop you replace the value in "c" with a new value and in the end you only have the last number you typed. You also have a variable "u" you don't even use.

```
def x():
    values = []
    for i in range(8):
        values.append(float(input()))
    avg = sum(values)/len(values)
    return avg, max(values), min(values)

print(x())
```

The new code you provided works when I run it, you probably had some code above it when you run it that interferes. The error message says that there is a TypeError: "int object is not callable". This means that you are trying to call an object of type int as if it were a function, but it is not a function. Make sure you have no variables above this code snippet named "float", "sum" or "len" as these are built-in functions. e.g. You shouldn't do sum = 5 choose another variable name.

Answer (score 0):

Your editted part debug..

```
def x(u):
      y=0
      values=[]
      for i in range(8):
        c=float(input("Enter the numbers: "))
        y=y+c
        values.append(c)
      avg=y/8
      return avg, ("The maximum is {:.0f}".format(max(values))),("The minimum is {:.0f}".format(min(values)))
print(x(1))
```

**Limitation of this above code.**

If someone directly enter without entering number or no right the number the error display `could not convert string to float` To resolve this issue try below code..

```
def x(u):
      y=0
      values=[]
      for i in range(8):
        t=True
        while t:
            try:  
                c=float(input("Enter the numbers: "))
                y=y+c
                values.append(c)
                t=False
            except ValueError:
                print("could not convert string to float Please enter a number not enter directly or")
      avg=y/8
      return avg, ("The maximum is {:.0f}".format(max(values))),("The minimum is {:.0f}".format(min(values)))
print(x(1))
```

**Output:-**

```
Enter the numbers: 
could not convert string to float Please enter a number not enter directly or enter the string..
Enter the numbers: 2
Enter the numbers: 4
Enter the numbers: six
could not convert string to float Please enter a number not enter directly or enter the string..
Enter the numbers: 1
Enter the numbers: 3
Enter the numbers: 5
Enter the numbers: 6
Enter the numbers: 7
Enter the numbers: 8
(4.5, 'The maximum is 8', 'The minimum is 1')
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def func():
    values = []
    for i in range(8):  
        values.append(float(input()))
    return (sum(values)/len(values), max(values), min(values))
```

I will write in that way.

1. Declaring an array
2. Iterating over array and fill it with inputted values.
3. Returning the average, max of array, min of array using built in functions in form of Tupple(its useful when returning more than one values from a function)

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.